# python if condition with two output

Tags: python

I do not know if this would be a duplicate question: I looked for a similar question but I didn't find it.

I am struggling a little bit with my python code and I hope someone will help me.

My purpose is this:

I want to scrape through a list, if the element inside a list is like a want, I'd like to print it if not I want to print no data.

this is my code but it does not work at all.

```
tags = soup('div') #from Beautifulsoup
for d in tags:
    if d.get('class') == "listing_details":
        print d.get('class')

else: 
    print 'no data'
```

This code prints as no data as the len(list).

I just want only one output if the first condition is not verified.

Could someone help me?

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

updated

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

I used that code and it works

```
class_list= list()
for d in tags:
    if d.get('class') == "listing_details":
        print d.get('class')
    class_list.append(d.get('class'))

if 'listing_details' not in class_list:
    print 'no data available'
```

it respects "*Simple is better than complex.*" but not "*Beautiful is better than ugly.*"

Comment: First, do NOT use `list` as a variable name, it is Python's Type.
Second, tell us what the old `list` variable holded or we can't replicate it.

Comment: Can you provide the list you use?

Comment: get on a list? are you using a dictionary rather than list?

Comment: @UrielEli the list is made by the outputs of  `tags = soup('div') `  from Beautifulsoup. They are different and a lot....  and unfortunately I suppose I cannot do a condition for one of them ...  :(

Comment: @Pippo,  it is a list

Comment: The `else` statement of a `for` loop will be executed if the loop does not end with a `break`, you will probably have to carry a flag and check it at the end of the loop as @falsetru suggests in his answer.

Comment: @Pippo he is doing `d.get(...)` not `tags.get(...)`, this means that the get operation is done on each element not on the list. It's perfectly possible.

Answer (score 0):

Use a variable to determine whether there was a matching element or not:

```
found = False
for d in list:
    if d.get('class') == "listing_details":
        print d.get('class')
        found = True
if not found:
    print 'no data'
```

BTW, as @Adirio commented, don't use `list` as a variable name. It will shadow builtin function/type `list`.

Comment: This would only print `listing_details` or `no data` once. Is this the desired behaviour? I thought he wanted to run over all the elements in the list.

Comment: @Adirio, Ah, I missed that. I will update the answer. Thank you for your comment.